# Adding Additional SQL Logic/Transformations to Query and Subquery

Tags: sql, transformation, case-when, data-extraction

I'm a bit stumped on how to approach this problem and haven't had much luck finding answers that really addressed it.

I'd like to take a set of trading data, extract the name of the underlying company from a column with a lot of noise in, and then combine that Name with the Buy or Sell of that particular trade.

Then, I'd like to look at each instance where there is are both a Buy and Sell of company and if so, label Buy trades as "Yes" and Sell trades as "Sold". So, if I had  17 "Pepsi_Buy" trades and  1 "Pepsi_Sell", each trade "Pepsi_Buy" would get a 'Yes' and the 1 "Pepsi_Sell" would get 'Sold' label.

If I had all 'Pepsi_Buy' and no 'Pepsi_Sell' then they'd all receive a "NO" label and alternatively, if only had 'Pepsi_Sell' then it too would receive a "NO".

I've been able to parse out the underlying company names and then perform a count on all of the results from CASE WHEN transformation. Now I'm starting to spin my wheels on how I can take the next step.

Here's my code if it helps give some context - thank you vm in advance for any sage insights!

```
SELECT UR.underlying_reference, 
   Count(*) AS NUMBER_MATCHES 

FROM   (SELECT CASE 
             WHEN Trade_Record IS NULL THEN NULL 
             WHEN Charindex('/', Trade_Record, 1) = 0 THEN 
             Substring(Trade_Record, (Charindex(' on ', Trade_Record 
             , 1)+4) , Charindex('.', Trade_Record, (Charindex(' on ', 
Trade_Record,1)+4)) 
             - (Charindex(' on ', Trade_Record, 1)+4)) 
             + '_' + BUY_SELL_FLAG 
             ELSE Substring(Trade_Record, (Charindex(' on ', 
                  Trade_Record,1)+4),Charindex('/', Trade_Record, 
(Charindex(' on ', 
                  Trade_Record, 1)+4)) - (Charindex(' on ', Trade_Record, 
1)+4)) 
                  + '_' + BUY_SELL_FLAG 
           END AS UNDERLYING_REFERENCE 
    FROM   tradeTable
    WHERE  recordDate = '6/29/2018' 
           AND BUY_SELL_FLAG IS NOT NULL) UR 
GROUP  BY UR.underlying_reference   
ORDER BY UR.underlying_reference ASC
```

This table would be my desired results. I've already got the Company+BuySell field to work but the MatchingLogic is what I am trying to tackle

```
Company+BuySell Combine Matching Logic
PEPSI CO _Buy   Y
PEPSI CO _Buy   Y
PEPSI CO _Buy   Y
PEPSI CO _Buy   Y
PEPSI CO _Sell  Sold
PEPSI CO _Sell  Sold

COCA COLA_Sell  Sold
COCA COLA_Sell  Sold
COCA COLA_Sell  Sold
COCA COLA_Sell  Sold

MCDs_Buy    N
MCDs_Buy    N
MCDs_Buy    N
MCDs_Buy    N
MCDs_Buy    N
MCDs_Buy    N

DRP_Buy     Y
DRP_Sell    Sold
DRP_Sell    Sold
DRP_Sell    Sold
DRP_Sell    Sold
DRP_Sell    Sold
DRP_Sell    Sold
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I posted a desired result table. If you think more info would help please let me know and I'll take care of it!

Comment: If you managed to get your data looking into two columns CompanyName Sold/Sell - using crt or a view that can be referenced - it will surely be simple to do a a CASE WHEN THEN ELSE using counts based on the same view/crt.

I.e. SELECT [CompanyName], CASE WHEN [BuySell] = 'Buy' THEN CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myView mv2 WHERE mv.[companyName] = mv2.[CompanyName] AND mv2.[BuySell] = 'Sell') > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' ELSE 'Sold' END AS [output]

Not nice but if you can't create a view for whatever reason, you could always paste the whole of your original query again into the SELECT count(*)

Answer (score 0):

I would use ANSI/ISO standard window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when num_buys = 0 or num_sells = 0 then 'No'
             when buy_sell_flag = '_buy' then 'Yes'
             when buy_sell_flag = '_sell' then 'Sold'
        end) as derived_logic
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when buy_sell_flag = '_buy' then 1 else 0 end) as num_buys,
             sum(case when buy_sell_flag = '_sell' then 1 else 0 end) as num_sells
      from t
     ) t;
```

The subquery is not strictly necessary but I think it makes the logic more readable.